# How to show image caption in ionicframework?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, ionic-framework

```html
<ion-view title="Categories">
                <ion-content ng-init="loadImages()">
                    <div id="catlist">
                        <div class="row" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-if="$index % 2 === 0">
                            <div class="col" ng-if="$index < images.length">
                                <a data-id="{{cats[$index].CategoryID}}" >
                                    <span id="Content" class="col col-25 ">{{cats[$index].CategoryName}}</span>
                                    <img ng-src="{{images[$index].src}}" width="100%" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col" ng-if="$index + 1 < images.length">
                                <a data-id="{{cats[$index+1].CategoryID}}" >
                                    <span id="Content" class="col col-25 ">{{cats[$index+1].CategoryName}}</span>
                                    <img ng-src="{{images[$index + 1].src}}" width="100%" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-view>
```

```css
#Content {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #f4f2f3;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 310px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  background-opacity: 0.1;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s;
}
```

I have create the 2*2 image grid and shows the image caption on top of the image. But image caption width doesn't fit to image width. I am using ionic framework. How can I adjust image caption width depends on image width?[image]

Comment: Please share us your CSS

Answer (score 0):

From checking in your css for #Content (this should be changed to class instead of id, because it suppose to has only one element for one id per page. But I don't think this why problem occur)

In your #Content style can you please try to change from

```
width: 310px;
```

to

```
width: 100%;
```

If this not work, try to add

```
display: block;
```

Hope this help, and sorry for my English :)

Comment: Thank you for your replay. Once i have test it and let you know the result

Comment: Can you use "ionic serve" command in your terminal to run your app in the browser to make it easier to check css overriding. I think there is some style override your style.